# Wordpress Sidebar Links

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

In this [wordpress site](http://www.allcardinfo.com/) you can see that the links in the sidebar of website is comes with build points. I am looking for the recent post without build points. How to correct it? Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace following code in style.css at line number 994:

```
.widget ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: circle inside;
}
```

With this code:

```
.widget ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}
```